# tesseract can't init russian language

Tags: c#, tesseract

My code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Clear();               

                var img = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);

                //var ocr = new TesseractEngine("./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.TesseractAndCube);

                var ocr = new TesseractEngine("./rus", "rus", EngineMode.TesseractAndCube);

                var page = ocr.Process(img);


                textBox1.Text = page.GetText();

            }
        }
```

Code works fine with English trained data, but it throws an error when I change it to Russian.

Here is the error:

> Tesseract.TesseractException: "Failed to initialise tesseract engine..
>   See https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/wiki/Error-1 for details."

My Tesseract version is 3.0.2.

I've downloaded Russian tessdata files from https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Data-Files#data-files-for-version-302

Comment: Can you confirm that you have 2 directories: `tessdata` with `tessdata/eng.traineddata` and `rus` with `rus/rus.traineddata`?

Comment: yes i have two  directories (sorry my bad english)

Comment: thank you for Suggested Edits

Comment: There might be an issue with old tesseract versions, where you need eng traineddata file even if you're not going to use it. Can you move your `rus.traineddata` to `tessdata/` directory and change it in your code as well (`                var ocr = new TesseractEngine("./tessdata", "rus", EngineMode.TesseractAndCube);
`)

Comment: I downloaded from one resource (english and russian )

Comment: It doesn't matter, move your rus.traineddata to tessdata directory and change code as described above.

Answer (score 2):

work for me

```
    Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();
    tesseract.setLanguage("rus");
    try {
        tesseract.setDatapath("/home/test/tessdata");
        String text = tesseract.doOCR(new File("/home/test/Pictures/photo.jpg"));
        System.out.print(text);
    } catch (TesseractException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

test data  - https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed that problem. Tesseract can run with single language (I've tried bul.traineddata). But "rus" always gives that result in logcat:

> Could not initialize Tesseract API with language=rus!

Of cause I've had rus.traineddata file in assets :-)